# How to return from async function?

Tags: python, return, python-asyncio, pyrogram

I have this function code, when I call it, output is my list printed but this list doesn't return.

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram import enums

async def search_for_deals(message_to_search):
    async with client:
        async for message in client.search_global(query=message_to_search, limit=40):
            if message.from_user.username not in filter_list:
                try:
                    filter_list.append(message.from_user.username)
                    message_list.append(message.text+'\n\n'+'@'+message.from_user.username+'\n'+str(message.date)+
                                              f'\n[Link to offer [{message.chat.title}]](https://t.me/{message.chat.username}/{message.id})')
                except Exception as error:
                    print(error)
                    continue
    print(message_list)    #output1
    return message_list

api_id = 'xxxxxx'
api_hash = 'xxxxxxx'

client = Client("mybot", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
filter_list, message_list = [], []

list = client.run(search_for_deals(str(input())))
print(list)    # needed output2
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
None
```

I still can't figure out how to return from this function.

Comment: What is `Client`, what does `Client.run` do…?

Comment: Oh, sorry about it, I used' from pyrogram import Client' . Client run triggers this function with the telegram client on

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
output = loop.run_until_complete(search_for_deals(str(input())))
```

instead of `output = client.run(search_for_deals(str(input())))`
and do not use the `list` as variable name, confuses with the list class